# Editing values in SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with a cell that has the following formula `=SUMPRODUCT(A20:K20;A22:K22)`. The problem is that I want to edit the value in `A20`, while calculating the result of the formula, but not in the original cell. I tried to do `=SUMPRODUCT(A20*0.2,B20:K20;A22:K22)`, but there is an error. How can I achieve this the right way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the original value of A20 in cell A19 and your factor in cell A18. Then in cell A20 just put

`=A19*A18`

This will allow you to change the factor at will - assuming cells A19 and A18 are available, if not somewhere else.

You cannot, AFAIK, put a calculation in sumproduct() like that, but, if it is possible someone will tell us...

Edit:
Based on Barry’s comment below, add a third array to the sumproduct ie a third set of cells - if they are available.. so you get :

```
=sumproductA20:K20,A22:K22,A24:K24)
```

So cells A24:K24 can have the factors in you need to use and they are easily visible. Good one Barry!

Comment: I have done something else, but in this direction as: `=A20*0.2*A22+SUMPRODUCT(B20:K20;B22:K22)`. Oh, thats something I never knew. Let's see if there are any other options.

Comment: @Cap I don't know if this is any better than Mike's answer or your suggestion in comment above, but you can add another array the same size as A20:K20, e.g. `=SUMPRODUCT(A20:K20,A22:K22,{0.2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1})` This would allow you to add a multiplier to any value in A20:K20 with 1 meaning the values are unchanged This syntax works for me but in non-English excel you may need different separators in {0.2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} - select A20:K20 in your original formula and press F9 key and you can see what separators need to be used